# After installing .net 4.5 custom forms authentications break

Tags: asp.net, .net, forms-authentication

I have just upgraded to VS 2012 from VS2010, and are having some issues with FormsAuthentication.

I have some old code which creates a custom auth cookie to store som information in it:

```
   public static int SetAuthCookie<T>(this HttpResponse responseBase, string name, bool rememberMe, T userData)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            var cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(name, rememberMe);
            var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);

            var newTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(ticket.Version,
                                                          ticket.Name,
                                                          ticket.IssueDate,
                                                          ticket.Expiration,
                                                          ticket.IsPersistent,
                                                          serializer.Serialize(userData),
                                                          ticket.CookiePath);

            var encodedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newTicket);

            cookie.Value = encodedTicket;
            responseBase.Cookies.Add(cookie);

            return encodedTicket != null ? encodedTicket.Length : 0;
        }
    }
```

After upgrading to .Net 4.5 HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated is always null. I have seen that there is a new way to authenticate in .Net 4.5, but I rather not use it, since I won't be able to upgrade the production enviroment from .Net 4.0. Is there a way to set the authentication when using a custom auth cookie?

Comment: I am from .NET Framework Compatibility Team. Would like to understand this better. Could you email us at netfx45compat at Microsoft dot com to discuss? If this impacting your production scenario, we would like to help address it too.

Comment: Of course, I will give you a buzz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to set the Current User myself in the Global.asax:

```
    private void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
    if (cookie != null)
    {
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);
        HttpContext.Current.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(new FormsIdentity(ticket), new string[0]);
    }
}
```

Why this has changed in .Net 4.5 I don't know.

Comment: did you ever figured out what changed?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are facing one of these problems:

http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Offtopic/thread/1791c5e3-4087-4e92-a460-51c5c4221f49

or a simpler configuration for the same:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1835788.aspx/1

Or a broken web.config as here:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1852961.aspx/1

Answer (score 1):

The machineKey is handled differently in .NET 4.5. You can add compatibilityMode="Framework20SP1" to your config:

(The above is the default for 2.0 / 4.0 applications but is not the default for 4.5 applications, so it will have to be set explicitly in the 4.5 application.)

Reference: http://forums.asp.net/t/1835788.aspx/1

Comment: Extra note this is part of your machine key  <machineKey compatibilityMode="Framework20SP1" validationKey="" decryptionKey="" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES"  /> Also don't forget that you will need to set the validation to match your other version